# Do I need to implement the CRUD Methods in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, scaffolding, grails-controller

I am using scaffolding in my application. However, I was wondering if I now really need to implement the CRUD Methods in my Controller class for example concerning production mode.

btw I am using `grails 2.3.4`

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather odd question. You don't need to do much at all - make your app the way you want. If the generated CRUD pages help you, use them, otherwise don't. You can use them as starter code, removing actions and other code that you don't need and adding new code as needed. You can create code by hand or via scripts. Do what works for you :)